# How to find value of one array that is associated with another value in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working on a project called 'tender management'. I created three arrays:

1. `tenders` array, which accepts project_name, company's name, cost, and any note for description
2. `companies` array, which stores names of all the companies that have given the tender
3. `costs` array, which stores costs given by the respective companies

The tender will be accepted for the minimum cost. For this, I used `min` to find the minimum cost from `costs`.

How do I find the respective company's name from `companies` or `tenders` that has this minimum cost?

Comment: Give a coded example.

Comment: Yes example code required. Also, think about the convenience of using hashes instead. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html

Comment: The code is too big to be posted here. Anyways my doubt is solved. Thank you